# Envio de email por PHP não mostra acentos corretamente

Tags: php, html, codificação-de-caracteres

### **Situação**

Tenho um sistema de email newsletter, nele é enviado emails para clientes todos os dias, porém percebi que ao usar acentos como `´~'^`, as palavras desconfiguram ficando assim: `Ã“AÃÃÃ` adiante.

Bom, já tentei incluir `<meta charset="UTF-8">` e outras codificações porém nada muda, além de salvar com codificação UTF-8.

### **Informações Importantes**

O Assunto também tem o mesmo problema, ou seja, o email inteiro, desde assunto a mensagem saem com acentos desconfigurados.

O code `php` está assim:

```
<?php              
$msg_para    = $_POST["msg_para"];
$msg_assunto = $_POST["msg_assunto"];
$msg_tipo    = $_POST["msg_tipo"];
$mensagem    = $_POST["mensagem"];
if($msg_para == "todos"){
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list-emails WHERE ativo = 'online'");
$total = mysql_num_rows($sql);
$mailok = 0;
$falha  = 0;
while($lista = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$email = $lista["email"];
$cabecalho  = "From: $a_nome <$a_email>";
$cabecalho .= "\nReply-To: $a_nome <$a_email>";
$cabecalho .= "\nContent-Type: $msg_tipo";
if(@mail($email,$msg_assunto,$mensagem,$cabecalho)){
$mailok = $mailok + 1;
$msg = "<font color=green>SUCESSO!</font>";
}
else{
$falha = $falha + 1;
$msg = "<font color=red>FALHA!</font>";
}
?>
<font face="Arial" size="2">Enviando para <b><?=$email?></b>...
<b><?=$msg?></b></font><br>
<?php } ?>
<script>alert("<?=$total?> e-mails deveriam ser enviados...\n<?=$mailok?> 
foram mandados corretamente,\n<?=$falha?> falharam!\n") </script>
<?php
}
else{
$cabecalho  = "From: $a_nome <$a_email>";
$cabecalho .= "\nReply-To: $a_nome <$a_email>";
$cabecalho .= "\nContent-Type: $msg_tipo";
if(@mail($msg_para,$msg_assunto,$mensagem,$cabecalho)){
$msg = "<font color=green>SUCESSO!</font>";
}
else{
$msg = "<font color=red>FALHA!</font>";
}
?>
<font face="Arial" size="2">Enviando para <b><?=$msg_para?></b>...
<b><?=$msg?></b></font><br><?php
}
}
else{
echo "<script>location.href='login.php'</script>";
}
?>
```

**O código na integra pode ser conferido [aqui](http://pastebin.com/ifZZXysb)**

*Resumidamente* preciso de alguma forma para colocar codificação UTF-8 ou qualquer outra que não tenha problemas com acentuações no email.

### @Edit 14/04/16 08:23 AM

Uma coisa que percebi é que o nome do e-mail setado na `config.php` sai com acentos normais, os únicos campos que tem esse problema são o de **assunto** e o de **mensagem**. O code do `config.php` está assim:

```
<?php
$host    = "4322-8922";
$usuario = "5";
$senha   = "4";
$banco   = "321";
mysql_connect($host,$usuario,$senha);
mysql_select_db($banco);
$a_nome          = "Téstê dê Ácëñtõs StáckÔvèrFlôw";
$a_email         = "diretoria@barietoner.com.br"; 
$formato_msg     = "Text/HTML"; 
$confirm_assunto = "Confirmação de Email $a_nome"; //esse assunto é especificamente para a parte de newsletter
$titulo          = "Máîs Úm Tèstê"; 
$url             = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";
$url_sist        = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";
?>
```

E o resultado do e-mail é assim:

[image: problema de acentos com email]

> Usar conversores de textos está fora de cogitação já que o envio o
>   email do email é feito direto pelo sistema, isso causaria uma lentidão
>   no processo.

Comment: Tenta isso: `utf8_encode($msg);`

Comment: @EdCesar, tentei colocar isso em $msg_assunto e $mensagem porém nada mudou, tem alguma ideia do que pode ser
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi **solucionado** simplesmente adicionando `utf8_decode()` nas variáveis `$_POST`, ou seja, não tinha nenhuma ligação com o `Content-Type` ou corpo da mensagem e nem com a codificação do arquivo.

Atualmente com a solução do problema, o  `code` está assim:

```
<?php              
$msg_para    = $_POST["msg_para"];
$msg_assunto = utf8_decode($_POST["msg_assunto"]);
$msg_tipo    = $_POST["msg_tipo"];
$mensagem    = utf8_decode($_POST["mensagem"]);
if($msg_para == "todos"){
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM n_emails WHERE ativo = 's'");
$total = mysql_num_rows($sql);
$mailok = 0;
$falha  = 0;
while($lista = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$email = $lista["email"];
$cabecalho  = "From: $a_nome <$a_email>";
$cabecalho .= "\nReply-To: $a_nome <$a_email>";
$cabecalho .= "\nContent-Type: $msg_tipo";
 if(@mail($email,$msg_assunto,$mensagem,$cabecalho)){
 $mailok = $mailok + 1;
 $msg = "<font color=green>SUCESSO!</font>";
 }
 else{
 $falha = $falha + 1;
 $msg = "<font color=red>FALHA!</font>";
 }
 ?>
 <font face="Arial" size="2">Enviando para <b><?=$email?></b>...
 <b><?=$msg?></b></font><br>
 <?php } ?>
 <script>alert("<?=$total?> e-mails deveriam ser enviados...\n<?=$mailok?> foram mandados corretamente,\n<?=$falha?> falharam!\n")</script>
 <?php
```

**Agradeço a quem tentou ajudar e espero que ajude outras pessoas que estejam com problemas também.**

Comment: Não entendi o down vote, está errada a forma que escrevi a resposta ou alguma coisa inclusa?

Comment: Para mim, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa configurar o cabeçalho do PHP.

Coloque isto no topo da página:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Se funcionar dê um UP aqui.

Comment: Infelizmente continua a mesma coisa, acredito que vou ter que setar o charset para cada um dos campos, é isso? Se sim, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Cara, tem uma outra coisa que vc pode fazer... Configure o seu editor para codificação utf-8.. Isso me ajudou uma vez...

Comment: já tinha feito isso amigo, problema já foi solucionado

Answer (score 2):

Como você tem estas linhas:

```
$msg_tipo    = $_POST["msg_tipo"];
$cabecalho .= "\nContent-Type: $msg_tipo";
```

é questão de garantir que a variável `$msg_tipo` tenha o charset correto, seja vindo do POST, ou pondo no código de envio.

O formato correto é este:

```
              Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
aqui você adapta pro seu caso  ---^      ^---- fundamental além do tipo certo, o charset
```

Notar que `text/html` foi só um exemplo, precisa setar de acordo com o conteúdo. O importante é acrescentar o `; charset="UTF-8"` ao final.

(não confundir com o `Content-Type` do header HTTP, estamos falando do header do email/MIME Type)

Além disso, é importante que a página onde está o formulário também esteja usando o charset correto. ISO-8859-1 e UTF-8 são os mais comuns e adequados para o envio.

Aqui tem mais algumas considerações (em inglês):

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_email

Comment: Fiz do modo que recomendou porém agora parece o seguinte erro: `parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /xxx/xx/public_html/xx/mod/envia_mail.php on line 265`

Comment: na linha 265 está: `$cabecalho .= "\nContent-Type: $msg_tipo"; charset="UTF-8";`

Comment: Suas aspas estão erradas. Precisa corrigir a sintaxe. Ou dá um "escape" nelas, ou usa concatenação e aspas simples. $cabecalho .= `"\nContent-Type: $msg_tipo"; charset=\"UTF-8\"";`

Comment: ou então `$cabecalho .= "\n".'Content-Type: '.$msg_tipo.'; charset="UTF-8"';`

Comment: lembre de testar com ISO-8859-1 se o problema persistir.

Comment: Infelizmente as 2 formas, inclusive alternando entre ISO-8859-1 e UTF-8, não funcionaram

Comment: então tem mais alguma coisa errada no código. Você conferiu o fonte do email pra ver se a saída ficou igual à pretendida? Pode ser algum detalhe errado na montagem geral dos cabeçalhos também. Olhar o source gerado é importante. Aliás, um detalhe extra, quebra de cabeçalho de email é com CRLF. Quanto ao campo "assunto", no link que eu postei tem uma descrição sobre os encodings. Não basta só acertar o charset, cabeçalho de "assunto" tem um encoding especial. (mas o mais importante é acertar o corpo do email primeiro)

Comment: É o jeito é estudar melhor isso e enquanto não consigo arrumar ir utilizando conversor de caracteres especiais, agradeço a ajuda @Bacco, muito obrigado

Comment: @VictorGomes dê uma olhada boa no source do email, provavelmente é alguma bobeirinha. Em vez de testar enviando, imprima na tela os dados, pra conferir. O treco em teoria é bem simples, basta achar a causa do problema. Mostre na tela os dados antes e depois do envio. Sugiro trocar os "\n" por "\r\n" também, que é o padrão para email. Se acertar o corpo do email, depois dá pra avançar na solução para o cabeçalho.

Answer (score -2):

Eu faço uso do PHPMailer e meus e-mails são enviados com a codificação correta, para isso eu acrescentei no meu script de e-mail, na primeira linha eu acrescentei o código abaixo:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: Cara infelizmente não funcionou, tentei adicionar tanto no script, como também no corpo do email

Comment: Qual o encoding de seus arquivos? Para testar, no terminal do linux faça como no exemplo abaixo (substituindo o "mail.php" pelo seu arquivo responsável por enviar o e-mail):

# file --mime mail.php

no meu caso, a resposta foi:

mail.php: text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: consegui resolver já amigo, eu postei abaixo como fiz, obrigado pela ajuda @asfelix

Answer (score -3):

Pode usar assim que funciona estava com o mesmo problema

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';

Comment: Boas-vindas Renato. O autor não está usando a biblioteca de terceiros, PHPMailer, mas sim sobre a função nativa do PHP, [`mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). Antes de responder é importante entender todos os pontos da pergunta e acaso a pergunta tenha falta de informações, o correto deverá ser votar/sinalizar para fecha-la e aguardar que o autor da pergunta edite-a, para melhorar.